# Change div class based on positive or negative value - issue with values between 1/0/-1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I'm using this snippet for changing class of div based on positive or negative values

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('.price-change').each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text()) < 0) {
        $(this).addClass('negative');
    }
else if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 0) {
    $(this).addClass('positive');
}
});</script>
```

I'm having issues with values that are in between 0 and 1 and 0 and -1. So if the value is -0.15 it will show green, although it needs to show red since there is - before value.

Why is that happening? What is the best way to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `console.log(parseInt($(this).text(),10))` and you'll see what is happening.  It's rounding -0.15 to the nearest whole number, which is 0, which in your case is positive.   You're comparing non-ints with ints.

Comment: With parseInt, anything between 0 and 1 is just 0. You cannot have negative zero or positive zero. Its just plain 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is that happening

Add `console.log(parseInt($(this).text(),10))` and you'll see what is happening.

`parseInt` converts to the nearest whole number (an integer).  -0.15 is not an integer so will round to zero, which in your case is positive.

> What is a way to fix it?

You can use `parseFloat()` instead:

```
$('.price-change').each(function() {
  var val = parseFloat($(this).text());
  $(this).addClass(val < 0 ? 'negative' : 'positive');
]);
```

or you can use other functions, such as [floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) which returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number (ie always rounds *down*).

```
$('.price-change').each(function() {
  var val = Math.floor($(this).text());
  $(this).addClass(val < 0 ? 'negative' : 'positive');
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. `parseInt` will convert the -0.15 to 0 while `parseFloat` will compare it to the actual -0.15.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.price-change').each(function() {
    if (parseFloat($(this).text()) < 0) {
      $(this).addClass('negative');
    } else if (parseFloat($(this).text()) >= 0) {
      $(this).addClass('positive');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Small example: http://jsfiddle.net/6mymcn4c/1/

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the help and explanation. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.parseFloat()`:

```
$('.price-change').each(function() {
  if (parseFloat($(this).text()) < 0) {
    $(this).addClass('negative');
  } else if (parseFloat($(this).text()) >= 0) {
    $(this).addClass('positive');
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.price-change').each(function() {
  if (parseFloat($(this).text()) < 0) {
    $(this).addClass('negative');
  } else if (parseFloat($(this).text()) >= 0) {
    $(this).addClass('positive');
  }
});
```

```css
.negative{
color: blue;}
.positive{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-change">1</div>
<div class="price-change">0</div>
<div class="price-change">-0.15</div>
<div class="price-change">-10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try and catch to handle these errors
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch.shtml
Or 
you can use If  condition and manually handle the output in these known conditions the result in the code

Finally you can use this :

$('.price-change').each(function() {var x =  parseFloat($(this).text();If(x>0){x.addClass('negative');}
else{ x.addClass('positive');}});